# zend pagination page range vs item count per page

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

This may be a very basic question. But it is not very clear to me, the difference between
setItemCountPerPage and setPageRange. The zend manual defines both as below. I don't see a difference on reading it. Could someone tell how they are different, may be in the context of actual usage. Thanks

setItemCountPerPage : Sets the maximum number of items to display on a page (default 10).

setPageRange : Sets the number of items to display in the pagination control (default 10). Note: Most of the time this number will be adhered to exactly, but scrolling styles do have the option of only using it as a guideline or starting value (e.g., Elastic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setItemCountPerPage` refers to the ACTUAL DATA you are paginating.

`setPageRange` refers to the PAGINATION CONTROLS (the little HTML snippet with links to the other pages). Check out the different pagination styles in your pagination controls and it will become very obvious what this is.

You can really use one without the other though they work together so well that I usually see no point in separating them.

Comment: thanks. about separating them, there are cases when you want to drop setPageRange like in the case of providing a REST web service, where you just return the data in a particular format without worrying about the presentation.

Comment: @krishna You are right! I guess REST would be a good place to separate them! Glad to be of help.